# extract oracle xml node

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a oracle clob and I want to extract part of it :
The clob:

```
<JobDetails>
 <ObjectDetails />
 <DestinationDetails>
  <AddressTo>test@gmail.com</AddressTo>
  <AddressCc></AddressCc>
  <AddressBcc></AddressBcc>
  <Subject>Automated email </Subject>
  <Message>Automated email </Message>
  <Attachment></Attachment>
  <Importance>False</Importance>
 </DestinationDetails>
</JobDetails>
```

I want to get from  up to /DestinationDetails>
 is not include every time the same nodes.
I don't want to just delete the beginning and the end of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast it to XMLTYPE and use XPath/XQuery

Older, deprecated syntax:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(XMLTYPE(clob_col), '/*/DestinationDetails')
FROM some_table
```

Newer XQuery syntax:

```
SELECT
  XMLQUERY('/*/DestinationDetails' PASSING XMLTYPE(clob_col) RETURNING CONTENT) xml_fragment
FROM some_table
```

Comment: The old syntax works, the new one not. It fails with error ORA 00902 invalid datatype. I believe is this line: AS XMLTYPE.

Comment: You are correct, I hadn't tested it - you didn't need the XMLCAST as you are retrieving an XMLTYPE. If you were targeting a leaf node / text content then you would want to cast it to a number or VARCHAR2